# How to pass `$(this)` as parameter to a "callready" function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize

The `leanModal` function triggers a modal with some parameters. One of this parameters is a function (`ready`) that will be executed once the `Modal` is open. The point is, I need to do some stuff inside that function (`ready`) just with the element (`tag`) which triggered the modal, so I need to pass `$(this)` as parameter to that function. The `leanModal()` function is provided by MaterializeCss which's the framework that I'm using.

I've been trying this, but `thisTag` is always undefined. I also have tried to pass directly `$(this)` to the function, but it also doesn't work at all, it's still undefined. So, how can I reach this?

```
$('.modal-trigger-editMedic').leanModal({
    thisTag: $(this),
    ready: function(thisTag){
        var refereeNum = thisTag.siblings("[name*='refereeNumToEdit']" )[0].value;
        $('#surname').val($("input[id*='medicNameToModal"+refereeNum+"'").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: youre defining thisTag as a parameter.. change this: `ready: function(){`

Comment: Are you using leanModal https://github.com/FinelySliced/leanModal.js

Comment: @pichfl I don't really know, it's a function provided by MaterializeCss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [the source code](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/js/leanModal.js), `.leanModal` supports a ready function (which is triggered once the modal is visible) but doesn't bind or send the element which triggered the modal, the easiest way to fix this is to store a reference outside. To do so, you need to iterate over the triggers yourself instead of relying on that functionality of provided by this jQuery plugin.

Like so:

```
var $surname = $('#surname'); // you should store the selector as a reference 
                              // outside the loop for better performance

$('.modal-trigger-editMedic').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); // this is the current item in the set of elements, 
                         // therefore our trigger element
                         // EDIT: using var makes this a local variable

    $this.leanModal({
        ready: function() {
            var refereeNum = $this.siblings("[name*='refereeNumToEdit']" )[0].value;

            $surname.val($("input[id*='medicNameToModal"+refereeNum+"'").val());
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it works, but the var `refereeNum` returns the value to the last reference to `$(this)` which's the last `.modal-triger-editMedic`. There are some `.modal-triger-editMedic` inside a list, and that script always returns me the reference to the last, I don't know if I'm explaining myself...

Comment: Oh sorry, I missed a rather important `var` statement. See the updated answer above.

Comment: I know that "Thank you" messages are "forbidden", so I'll just tell you: you are the boss.

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside the leanModal it becomes this. Try setting a var to $(this) and pass that through.

```
var that = $(this);
$('.modal-trigger-editMedic').leanModal({
    thisTag: that,
    ready: function(thisTag){
        var refereeNum = thisTag.siblings("[name*='refereeNumToEdit']" )[0].value;
        $('#surname').val($("input[id*='medicNameToModal"+refereeNum+"'").val());
    }
});
```

Comment: yes it does, that will contains the reference to the query object of this of the scope where it is executed. But instand of using thisTag:that, just use **that** in the **ready** callback and it'll work. Ofc we suppose that the this at this moment refer to the tag element.